# Creating a geofence around a single lat and lng

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, w3c-geolocation

I'm using html5 geolocation to check if people are in a certain location before opening up an app to them however, I was wondering if it's possible to add a radius that allows people to be within say 200m of that particular point?

Comment: Of course it is possible. Anything else?

Comment: Ah sorry I meant to say are there any examples of the code that is required to do this.

Comment: You should look around, there's all you need on Stack Overflow already. The API gives you the user's coords, you have coords for your location, so you just need to calculate the distance between those points and see if it's lower than 200m.

Comment: Ah thanks very much, that's a useful way of thinking about it.